# Elixir operator ~w(list)

Tags: elixir

I am following this example exercice of elixir
https://github.com/seven1m/30-days-of-elixir/blob/master/04-list.exs

I am trying to find in the docs what ~w does but cannot find it

```
ExUnit.start

defmodule ListTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  def sample do
    ["Tim", "Jen", "Mac", "Kai"]
  end

  test "sigil" do
    assert sample == ~w(Tim Jen Mac Kai)
  end
end
```

So what does `~w(Tim Jen Mac Kai)` do in this test?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are called [sigils](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html) in Elixir. They are defined using a function/macro named `sigil_` concatenated to the letter after `~`. `~w` is therefore defined as `sigil_w` in the `Kernel` module. [Here's](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.5.1/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L4542) the source code of `Kernel.sigil_w/2` in Elixir 1.5.1 and [here's](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#sigil_w/2) its documentation.